Выбрать третье слово из строки, регулярные выражения
Есть такая строка:
string = "Прикрепление #1 doc vk.com/doc111111111_1111111111 (111111111_1111111111.ogg https://psv2.userapi.com/d/a1/afsg/asdwegesgsdffasdagrfehseferwgeXzMmuGqFlYrsaOSHvE3lzZmEQpfUAGahFoDDjV.ogg)"

из которой необходимо достать третье слово doc.
Моих сил в регулярных выражениях хватило чтобы только выбрать первые три слова:
regex = "^[А-я]+\s+#\d+\s[A-z]+"

Вывод:
Прикрепление #1 doc

Как отделить от этой строки необходимое слово?

Вы можете использовать группу ^[А-я]+\s+#\d+\s([A-z]+) после чего получать используя re.findall(regex, string)[0]

Да, все получилось, спасибо, но можете объяснить почему при добавлении скобок, выделилась именно это слово?

^(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+)

.split()[2] не подходит? И регулярки не нужны.

@АлексейР подходит, но я изучаю регулярки, поэтому немного практики не повредит

Вы уточните вопрос: 1) вам нужно выбрать любое третье по счету слово, 2) слово, идущее за "#" или 3) именно слово "doc"?

@strawdog слово идущее за #n, вместо "doc" может быть любое слово

@WhyNot00 Скобки - это группировка, именно она и является результатом поиска шаблона, если она есть в регулярке.

@CrazyElf понял, спасибо

Чтобы найти третье слово, отделенное пробелом, можно str.split() использовать:
>>> n = 3; s.split(None, n)[n-1]
'doc'

Если нужно именно регулярное выражение:
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"(\S+\s+){3}", s)[1]
'doc '

Это ожидает, что есть пробел после 3го слова—легко убрать это требование при желании.
